# Compute number of direct report for each employee in the organization (aggregation)

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions, window-functions

FYI I use Redshift SQL.

I have a database that looks roughly like the one below (the database has multiple columns that I'll abstract away for simplicity).

This table is a representation of the hierarchical tree within my organization.

```
employee    manager
--------    -------
daniel      louis
matt        martha
martha      kim
laura       matt
michael     martha
...
```

As you can see, matt appears in two distinct records, one as the employee and the other as laura's manager. Martha appears in three records, one as an employee and in two other as manager.

I'd like to find a way to compute the number of direct reports each employee has. A conditional count in which the criteria would be where `employee = manager`, perhaps?

I guess I could find this information using a subquery and then join it back but I was wondering if there was a more "elegant" way to do this making use of window functions maybe.

The expected output for the table above would be:

```
employee    manager    direct_reports
--------    -------    --------------
daniel      louis      0
matt        martha     1
martha      kim        2
laura       matt       0
michael     martha     0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    t.employee,
    t.manager,
    (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.manager = t.employee) direct_reports
from mytable t
```

This should be a quite efficient method, especially with an index on `(employee, manager)`.

Comment: Does the job! Performance-wise, I'm not sure which one is more efficient between yours and Gordon's but I like it a bit better your in-line approach. Can you elaborate on your comment about the index (employee, manager)? Seems like Gordon's is a bit faster as is.

Comment: @DanielSegura: both approaches are fine (and both will take advantage of the index I mentioned). I guess that which one will perform best would depend on the distribution of your data. You would need to benchmark both solutions againts your real data to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select em.employee, em.manager, count(ew.employee)
from employees em left join
     employees ew
     on ew.manager = em.employee
group by em.employee, em.manager;
```

Comment: This worked very well, Gordon. Thank you very much.